# The requested route has not been mapped in Spark for Accept

Tags: spark-java

I have configured a '/metric' endpoint this way

```
get("/data",(req,res) -> "metrics invoked");
```

The logs give me this when i try to hit the endpoint

```
INFO: The requested route [/data] has not been mapped in Spark for Accept: [text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8]
```

Any pointers on what i might be missing?

Answer (score 0):

I has to do with the Accept header sent by the client.  Spark is complaining it can't respond how the client has asked.